# Can someone find the error and verify my Swift NSURLSession code?

Tags: swift, http, post, nsurlsession

I am writing my first, basic IOS app using Swift that will poll a Proliphix IP Thermostat and display the temperature. I have converted an HTTP Post to NSURLSession using Paw, but the converted code appears to have a 3 syntax errors when I load it in Xcode Playground.

My goal right now is to get this working in Playground, but ultimately use it in my App code. Could someone please load this code in your own Xcode Playground and fix the error and make it work? The URL is a public IP address of the thermostat and If working correctly, it will poll the thermostat and return a value for OID4.3.2.3 and = something like 772& (currently 77.2 degrees).

```
class MyRequestController {
    func sendRequest() {
        /* Configure session, choose between:
           * defaultSessionConfiguration
           * ephemeralSessionConfiguration
           * backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:
         And set session-wide properties, such as: HTTPAdditionalHeaders,
         HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy, requestCachePolicy or timeoutIntervalForRequest.
         */
        let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        /* Create session, and optionally set a NSURLSessionDelegate. */
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

        /* Create the Request:
           My API (POST http://my-thermostat.dyndns.org:8083/get)
         */

        var URL = NSURL(string: "http://my-thermostat.dyndns.org:8083/get")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // Headers

        request.addValue("Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        // Form URL-Encoded Body

        let bodyParameters = [
            "OID4.3.2.3": "",
        ]
        let bodyString = self.stringFromQueryParameters(bodyParameters)
        request.HTTPBody = bodyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

        /* Start a new Task */
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                // Success
                let statusCode = (response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                println("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")
            }
            else {
                // Failure
                println("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    /**
     This creates a new query parameters string from the given NSDictionary. For
     example, if the input is @{@"day":@"Tuesday", @"month":@"January"}, the output
     string will be @"day=Tuesday&month=January".
     @param queryParameters The input dictionary.
     @return The created parameters string.
    */
    func stringFromQueryParameters(queryParameters : Dictionary<String, String>) -> String {
        var parts: [String] = []
        for (name, value) in queryParameters {
            var part = NSString(format: "%@=%@",
                name.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                value.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            parts.append(part)
        }
        return "&".join(parts)
    }

    /**
     Creates a new URL by adding the given query parameters.
     @param URL The input URL.
     @param queryParameters The query parameter dictionary to add.
     @return A new NSURL.
    */
    func NSURLByAppendingQueryParameters(URL : NSURL!, queryParameters : Dictionary<String, String>) -> NSURL {
        let URLString : NSString = NSString(format: "%@?%@", URL.absoluteString!, self.stringFromQueryParameters(queryParameters))
        return NSURL(string: URLString)!
    }
}
```

I assume I need the following above this code in Playground to work properly?

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground
```

Last, the HTTP Post I used to convert was from the following and Paw converted this to NSURLSession above.

```
POST /get HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: my-thermostat.dyndns.org:8083
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.2 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.4) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 11

OID4.3.2.3=
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I create a playground with your code I get three errors.

One in the function `sendRequest()` where you must change this line:

`let statusCode = (response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode`

to

`let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode`

(`as!` instead of `as`)

One in the function `stringFromQueryParameters` where you must change the following line

`parts.append(part)`

to

`parts.append(part as String)`

(add `as String`)

And one in the function `NSURLByAppendingQueryParameters` where you must change this:

`return NSURL(string: URLString)!`

to this:

`return NSURL(string: URLString as String)!`

(add `as String`)

And then the compiler seems satisfied...at least on my machine :-)

And yes, you need to import Foundation and XCPlayground as you figured out already.

Furthermore, if you need to make asynchronous calls...as is the case here, you'll need this method in the top of your code:

`XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()`

(you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/XCPlayground.html))

And finally, to actually see your code run, you can add this to the bottom of your code, after the class definition:

```
let requestController = MyRequestController()
requestController.sendRequest()
```

Here is the complete code

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

class MyRequestController {
    func sendRequest() {
        /* Configure session, choose between:
        * defaultSessionConfiguration
        * ephemeralSessionConfiguration
        * backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:
        And set session-wide properties, such as: HTTPAdditionalHeaders,
        HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy, requestCachePolicy or timeoutIntervalForRequest.
        */
        let sessionConfig =   NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        /* Create session, and optionally set a NSURLSessionDelegate. */
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

        /* Create the Request:
        My API (POST http://my-thermostat.dyndns.org:8083/get)
        */

        var URL = NSURL(string: "http://my-thermostat.dyndns.org:8083/get")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

       // Headers

        request.addValue("Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        // Form URL-Encoded Body

        let bodyParameters = [
            "OID4.3.2.3": "",
         ]
        let bodyString = self.stringFromQueryParameters(bodyParameters)
        request.HTTPBody = bodyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

        /* Start a new Task */
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                // Success
                let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                println("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")
            }
            else {
                // Failure
                println("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    /**
    This creates a new query parameters string from the given NSDictionary. For
    example, if the input is @{@"day":@"Tuesday", @"month":@"January"}, the output
    string will be @"day=Tuesday&month=January".
    @param queryParameters The input dictionary.
    @return The created parameters string.
    */
    func stringFromQueryParameters(queryParameters : Dictionary<String, String>) -> String {
        var parts: [String] = []
        for (name, value) in queryParameters {
            var part = NSString(format: "%@=%@",
               name.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
            value.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            parts.append(part as String)
        }
        return "&".join(parts)
    }

    /**
    Creates a new URL by adding the given query parameters.
    @param URL The input URL.
    @param queryParameters The query parameter dictionary to add.
    @return A new NSURL.
    */
    func NSURLByAppendingQueryParameters(URL : NSURL!, queryParameters : Dictionary<String, String>) -> NSURL {
        let URLString : NSString = NSString(format: "%@?%@", URL.absoluteString!, self.stringFromQueryParameters(queryParameters))
       return NSURL(string: URLString as String)!
    }
}

let requestController = MyRequestController()
requestController.sendRequest()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your time! One last question; how to I see the results in playground? I am looking for the OID value that is returned. Do I need a print statement?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to see that you're making progress :-) You don't need a print statement. If you look in the right side of the playground there should be some output. Right now you have an answer from the server (in your completion handler), and to see the actual data that was returned, you can do something like this: `let returnData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` which - hopefully - should show you "OID4.3.2.3=827&" in the right side of the playground.

Comment: Ok. Slowly, but surely, I am getting there. Where would I put that line in the code? After the /* Start a new Task */ section? Where did you see "OID4.3.2.3=827&"? I do see output in the right side of Playground, but do not see this. Ultimately, I need to figure out how to reference the returned data in my app, but one step at a time:-)

Comment: I now see the OID data. Ultimately, I need to figure out how to reference the returned data in my app and present it formatted like "82.7 F". Much appreciation! You have gotten me much further. This is my first time to ever write an app and I am not a coder:-)

Comment: You are indeed. When you call `dataTaskWithRequest` on the session object you provide a completionHandler, which is code you like to execute when server returns an answer to you. In your code  you start out by checking whether you received an error or not. If you didn't you look at the statusCode print that out. After that you can map the data from the server to something you can read (perhaps you should add a check to see if the statusCode indicates success or failure). When you add the line, you should see the "OID4.3.2.3=827&" in the right side.

Comment: :-) Ok, off to working on the app now that I am getting some data to work with.

Comment: Ah..you figured it out I see :-) Glad I could help. Have fun with your app and with programming and just ask if you get stuck again.

Comment: Thanks again! Appreciate your willingness to answer questions.

Comment: You're welcome. We've all been there, in fact, we're all there, trying to wrap our heads around how to do one thing or another in some programming language on some platform several times every day